Differential Geometer's submanifolds vs. Calculus Student's submanifolds
Let $ M $ be a(n "abstract") smooth manifold of dimension $ n $. According to Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Definition 1 (Differential Geometer's Submanifold). A $ k $-dimensional (embedded) submanifold of $ M $ is a subset $ S\subset M $ such that for every $ p\in S $ there exists a chart $ (U,\phi) $ of $ M $ such that $ S $ is a $ k $-slice of $ U $, i.e. such that
$$
\phi(U\cap S) = \{(x^\prime,x^{\prime\prime})\in \mathbb R^k\times \mathbb R^{n - k} : x^{\prime\prime} = 0\}
$$
for some disjoint tuples of variables $ x^\prime = (x^{i_1},\dots,x^{i_k}) $ and $ x^{\prime\prime} = (x^{j_1},\dots,x^{j_{n - k}}) $ under the identification of $ \mathbb R^n $ with $ \mathbb R^k\times \mathbb R^{n-k} $.

According to this definition, a $ 2 $-dimensional submanifold of the $ 3 $-dimensional manifold $ M = \mathbb R^3 $ is a subset $ S\subset \mathbb R^3 $ such that for every $ p\in S $ there is a chart $ (U,\phi) $ such that for instance
$$
\phi(U\cap S) = \{((x,y),z)\in \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^1 : z = 0 \}
$$
under the identification $ \mathbb R^3\cong \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^1 $.
Well, I've noticed that calculus textbooks sometimes define submanifolds in a different way: to them

Definition 2 (Calculus Student's Submanifold). A $ k $-dimensional submanifold of $ \mathbb R^n $ is a subset $ S\subset \mathbb R^n $ such that for every $ p\in S $ there exists a neighborhood $ U $ of $ p $ in $ \mathbb R^n $, an open set $ V $ in $ \mathbb R^k $ and a diffeomorphism $ \phi\colon U\cap S\to V $.

Here $ U\cap S $ is not open, so in this case "$ \phi\colon U\cap S\to V $ is a diffeo" means that for every $ q\in U\cap S $ there is some smooth map $ \tilde\phi\colon N\to V $ defined in a neighborhood of $ q $ in $ \mathbb R^n $ such that $ \tilde\phi{\restriction_{U\cap S}} = \phi $, and $ \phi $ is invertible with differentiable inverse.
I am wondering: why we require $ \phi $ to be differentiable? Isn't it enough to ask for $ \phi $ to be a homeomorphism? I think that even in this weaker case we can show that every calculus student's submanifold is a differential geometer's submanifold and viceversa.
How can one prove that given a calculus student's submanifold $ S $ then $ S $ is a submanifold in the sense of definition 1?

Whops, just a typo. I edited.

That would be called a wishful thinking. Did you try to work out examples such as the graph of $|x|$?

As the charts in the first definition are diffeomorphisms, the two definitions can only be equivalent if $\phi$ is also a diffeomorphism

@MartinFrenzel Are you claiming that to build a chart $ (U.\phi) $ around $ p $ which is compatible with the differentiable structure of the manifold $ \mathbb R^n $, $ \phi\colon U\to V $ must be differentiable? This is true, but I don't see how I can build such a chart starting from the diffeo $ \phi\colon U\cap S\to V $ whose existence is guaranteed by Def. 2.

@GeometriaDifferenziale Are you asking how to show construct a chart such as in definition 1 from the map $\phi:U\cap S\to V$ from definition 2?

When I wrote this post I was thinking about how one can prove that the two definitions are equivalent, ad it seemed to me that the smoothness condition if def. 2 was unnecessary. After I posted the question I realized that I wasn't able to show that "2 implies 1" even with assuming the differentiability hypothesis. So yes, I'll modify my question to reflect that.

There is an obvious way in which these two definitions are not equivalent. Definition 1 applies to any abstract manifold. Definition 2 applies only to submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$. Even if every manifold can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ for some $n$ (true in the most canonical definition of "manifold", but false for some generalizations), if you use such an embedding to apply definition 2, it is not immediately clear that the concept of submanifold wouldn't depend on the particular embedding used.
